# Stellar amount sent from Ledger Nano S wallet to a destination wallet address but not received

Tags: transactions, assets, xlm, wallets, ledger-nano

I have some amount of Stellar on my Ledger Nano S wallet and tried to send it to another wallet address.
The transaction is successful. Although the amount is decreased from my ledger wallet and the transaction in https://stellar.expert/explorer/public exists and is done successfully, the destination wallet did not receive the amount. The point is that when I search the destination wallet address in [this address](https://stellar.expert/explorer/public), there is no Stellar amount in the destination.
How is it possible? Where are they?